# How to avoid screen flickering when a control must be constantly repainted in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, onpaint

I have a simple panel that is used as a drawing surface.  The goal here is to draw a 4 pixel wide outline around a child ListView under certain circumstances.  I would like to make the outline pulsate when something can be dragged into it.

I am just drawing a simple rectangle around the ListView and updating the opacity of the rectangle inside of a timer tick event.  When the opacity is changed, the border is re-drawn.  I am double-buffering the painting at this point.  I am also only allowing a redraw every 15 ticks or so (the timer interval is 20 ms).  After all of this, the drawing process still flickers a bit.  This is not acceptable, so I need some guidance on how I could avoid this.

I don't see a way around painting the control quite often.  There needs to be a smooth transition from opaque to solid and back again.  When I lower the tick interval enough (down to about 300 -500 ms), the flashing stops, but the refresh rate is too slow.

I am open to any and all ideas.  Perhaps the way I am approaching this is just plain wrong, or perhaps one of you have already created a glow effect and know what to do.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled on a solution for this if anyone is interested.  It turns out that the flashing is caused by the painting of the background.  I used SetStyle to tell the control that I will be handling all of the painting.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
         ControlStyles.Opaque |
         ControlStyles.UserPaint |
         ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

I then first paint a transparent color over the region, and then I paint my border.  I bit of a hack, but it works like a charm.

EDIT:  And remember to double buffer the image as well.

Answer (score 3):

Set DoubleBuffered = true on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a strong answer, but since you have none, I'll post anyway:

First, I have never used the System.Drawing.ImageAnimator class, but could that be a better approach for you?

Second, if that fails, have you tried *not* using double-buffering?  It's a long shot, but maybe your double-buffering code is actually making it worse.

Comment: +1 because you alerted me to the ImageAnimator class which is useful for another project of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry in advance that this likely won't help but: WPF has animations and could at least in theory do this smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but have you tried

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

On the Panel Control?

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to look at doing the drawing on a bitmap and then just displaying the bitmap if it has changed.  Just my 2c.

Comment: This is the double-buffering method that I have been using.